# Can't overwrite Core data iOS/objective C

Tags: ios

so I'm trying to overwrite/update a value saved from core data. when the back button is pressed (gets the textfield data and then overwrites the data using that). But it just keeps adding new data in. Here's my code in the back button:
The IF statement is just checking what the index is so it knows which view controller to go back to. goBackMVC just takes it back to a certain view controller.

```
- (IBAction)btnBack:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

   if (self.viewControllerIndex == 3) {
        NSLog(@"test");
        [self saveDataMethod];
        [self goBackMVC];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

saveDataMethod:

- (void) saveDataMethod {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    FavouriteItem *favouriteItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavouriteEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    favouriteItem.webName = self.txtName.text;
    favouriteItem.webURL = self.txtURL.text;
    favouriteItem.imageURL = self.txtImageURL.text;
    NSLog(@"favouriteItem.webName %@", favouriteItem.webName);

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

    }
}
```

My question is how can I overwrite the data instead of just adding it? Thanks.

**edit: I've searched around and a lot of solutions have arrays, but I'm not allowed to use arrays**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you insert a new entity to your core data :

```
FavouriteItem *favouriteItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavouriteEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Instead fetch the required entity :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favorits" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
```

To get the required entity create an NSPredicate instance to filter the required entity (in case you have more than one) and use it in your request :

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:<Your filter string>];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray* entities = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest  error:&error];
if ([entities count] == 1) {
   // Get the entity and update necessary fields and save in context
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, quick question. by "your filter string" should I just use all three of my favouriteItem.webName etc as the string?

Comment: That depends on which attribute(s) defines an entity as unique.

Comment: None of them define one as unique, there could be 5 entries with all the same values (not likely, but could happen)

Comment: Then replace the == 1 with > 0 and update each of these entities